# Core data background fetch not working

Tags: iphone, core-data, background, fetch

```
- (IBAction)findContact:(id)sender {

    CoreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//    NSManagedObjectContext *context =
//        [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    managedContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    //[context setParentContext:[self managedObjectcontext]];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc =
    [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts"
                inManagedObjectContext:managedContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == %@)",
     _name.text];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    [managedContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        _objects = fetchedObjects;

            NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

            NSLog(@"data= %@", [_objects description]);
            if (_objects == nil) {
                _status.text = @"No matches";
            } else {
                matches = _objects[0];
                _address.text = [_objects valueForKey:@"address"];
                _phone.text = [_objects valueForKey:@"phone"];
                _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d matches found", [_objects count]];
            }

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, can you explain what the purpose of doing the following is for:

first you create a new context with a private concurrency type.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Now you take that context and reassign it to something else?

```
context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
```

Now the context that you are using is the one you defined in your appDelegate...

Furthermore, assuming that the context defined in your appDelegate is correct, you are performing a fetch request in the context asynchronously. Then on the following lines you check for the results of that fetch without knowing whether or not the fetch request has been returned or not (since it is asynchronous). This explains why you see the results the second time since they have been fetched by then. A quick fix would be to sprinkle in some GCD into the context block like so:

```
[context performBlock:^{        
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
       _objects = fetchedObjects;
       if (_objects == nil) {
           _status.text = @"No matches";
       } else {
           NSLog(@"data= %@", [_objects description]);
           NSManagedObject *matches = _objects[0];
           _address.text = [matches valueForKey:@"address"];
           _phone.text = [matches valueForKey:@"phone"];
           _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d matches found", [_objects count]];
       }
    });
}];
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: This is not working, it shows the error where I assigned matches = _objects[0], the error is "variable is not assignable(missing _block type specifier).

Comment: My apologies, I edited my answer and created a temporary variable to store the results of the fetch and then assign it to the instance variable in the main queue. Try it again, it works on the sample app I just wrote...

Comment: Still the problem is same.
I am doing background fetching of data and displaying it to respective text fields. Here I am assigning first object after search operation if I find more than one object in fetched objects and assigning it to NSManagedObject matches but I am not able to do it. Thanks in advance...

Comment: put the declaration of matches within the block instead of declaring it outside the block, will edit my answer now

Comment: When you get the error "variable is not assignable(missing _block type specifier)" it means that you are trying to assign a variable within a block that was created outside of that block. Since the block keeps a copy of the externally defined variables that are used in the block, you must use the __block specifier before the variable declaration to let the compiler know that you are going to be editing the variable within the block and thus you don't want the standard read-only copy. I recommend looking at 2012 WWDC session 712 on asynchronous design patterns:)

Comment: If I write if{...} else {...} outside the block and rest of the things inside then error disappears but I cant get any data on first tap of fetch button, I have to tap the button second time to get any data.

Comment: If you are using a tableview why not try calling reloadData once the fetch returns?

Comment: No I am not using tableview, i am just displaying first object  which is found by searching, in respective textfields.
Right now my app get crashed when I search for anything, say "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98c0800'
".

Comment: Are you saying that using my code you are still getting the variable not assignable error? Furthermore, why not calling setNeedsDisplay on your views after the fetch returns. It seems that your view is only updating when you press the button again and not when the fetch finishes...

Comment: Declaring NSManagedObject inside the block I am not getting that error but my app crashes when I search for anything. Please suggest a way to solve this.

Comment: firstly your NSPredicate is wrong, you are checking for equality and not assignment thus you need to use the double equals ie. [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name == %@)",
 _name.text]; Lastly, i would recommend adding the exception breakpoint in Xcode so you can see where your code is crashing. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: I think your crash is due to calling -[NSArry count] since the array is obviously nil, updated my answer

Comment: Nope the crash remains still as it was.

Comment: put the exception breakpoint in and move your NSLog into the else statement then let me know where it crashes

Comment: It crashes when execution reaches to context performBlock:^

Comment: reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x92e3000'

Comment: I'm not following, its simply not possible that it is crashing on context performBlock with the error '-[__NSArrayI length]:unrecognized selector sent to instance' since those two methods are unrelated. Would you feel comfortable sending me your code otherwise I'm slightly unsure as to whether or not you have the exception breakpoint on correctly since it will show you the exact line and variable causing the crash

Comment: I have just edited my code and posted current code please check it

Comment: I edited your code but it seems you rejected it, please move your NSLog statement into the else block

Comment: Hi Paras, did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the perform block call. The fetch is trivial and should take a mere split second, so it is OK to perform it on the UI thread.

*Don't let this non-issue seduce you into adopting third party frameworks that promise simplifications but harbour (uncontrollable) complexities of their own.*

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Code below was not tested

To perform a background fetch you first need a background context.
As @Daniel_G stated, you are allocating a new context and then override it with an existing context (probably your main context).

To create a background context, you will need a `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`:

```
bgContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
bgContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = //self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator (the main managed object context coordinator)
//You can set here the undo-manager to nil as well
```

Now the we have a live background context we can perform the fetch and import the data to our export context/thread:

Your first option here is to use the persistent store cach and import the entire object:
(the result type of your fetch request in this case is `NSManagedObjectResultType`)

```
NSManagedObjectContext* exportContext = self.managedObjectContext; //capture the export context
[bgContext performBlock:^{//Executed on a background thread (most likely not main)
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* matched = [bgContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    //Check for errors, and count ...
    //
    //@note: objects contained in matched are not safe to access (even read only ops) in 
    //any other queue than this
    NSManagedObjectID* theId = [matched[0] objectID];
    [exportContext performBlockAndWait:^{ //keep the import context alive just in case
        //This code is executed on the calling object context queue (probably main)
        NSManagedObject* imported = [exportContext objectWithID:theID]; //Will not perform I/O
        //Extract the information you need from the imported data.
        //if your export context is not main, you will need to update UI elements
        //on the main thread (use GCD with main queue ...) and load the data to a
        //structure other than a NSManagedObject before moving to the main thread.
        //
        //@note: If the object matched is deleted after you've taken its ID and before you
        //       access it on this thread, an exception will be thrown
    }];
}];
```

The second option here (since it seems you directly update your UI):
Build your fetch request like this:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contacts"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"address",@"phone"];
//Any other settings that you need for your request ...
```

By executing this request in your background context, you get an array of dictionaries containing the information you requested.
This makes the fetch more efficient (faster).
Your fetch code should look something like:

```
[bgContext performBlock:^{//Executed on a background thread (most likely not main)
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* matched = [bgContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    //Check for errors, and count ...
    //
    //@note: matched is an array of dictionaries that can be passed between threads safely
    NSDictionary match = matched[0];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{//Executed on main thread
       _address.text = [match valueForKey:@"address"];
       _phone.text = [match valueForKey:@"phone"];
       _status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d matches found", [matched count]];
    });
}];
```

In general, do not access managed object outside their context's executing queue (not even for read operations).